# UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to remove these warnings:

```
UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey is deprecated

UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey is deprecated

UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey is deprecated
```

I am getting above warnings in these statements:

```
CGPoint beginCentre = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey] CGPointValue];

CGPoint endCentre = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey] CGPointValue];

CGRect keyboardBounds = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: just don't use those keys.

If you actually read the documentation, it will tell you you should use UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey and UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey.

Comment: if i use this UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey , the points shows (0 , 0) it is not working why?                                                                                                                                                                               CGPoint beginCentre = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGPointValue];
 
NSLog(@"beginCentre = %d-------------------%d", beginCentre.x , beginCentre.y);

Comment: however, UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey etc. does not take into account the rotation, whereas UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey does

Answer (score 5):

`UIkeyboardboundsuserinfokey` is not working porper in IOS 6 ..

use the `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` or `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` key instead of `uikeyboardboundsuserinfokey`

Answer (score 3):

Just change this

```
CGPoint beginCentre = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey] CGPointValue];

CGPoint endCentre = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey] CGPointValue];

CGRect keyboardBounds = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
```

to this

```
CGPoint beginCentre = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey"] CGPointValue];

CGPoint endCentre = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey"] CGPointValue];

CGRect keyboardBounds = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:@"UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"] CGRectValue];
```

see the difference?

```
 @"UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"
```

it works fine to me

Comment: NO. Hard-coding the value of one of these variables is worse than using the variable itself.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is marked as deprecated means that it can (and most likely will) be removed in any future versions of the SDK.  If you ignore the warnings, then your code will most likely not work in the future when newer versions of the SDK are released.

If you get a warning about this, check the documentation (as jtbandes suggested) and this will give you information about what to use instead.